# Why am I getting "System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid"?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

This code is for getting all the books in my library app from an SQL server using the C# SqlDatAdapter from `System.Data.SqlClient`. This is adding all of the books to a `List<Book>` where book is an declared object class.

```
allBooks.Add(new Book((String)i["title"], (String)i["author"], (Boolean)i["checkedOut"], (String)i["checkedOutTo"], (DateTime)i["dueDate"], (Double)i["Dues"], (int)i["extensions"], (String)i["imageURL"], (String)i["description"]));
```

Comment: Do any of those fields contain null in the database? If so, they'll be equal to DBNull.Value in code, which is not castable to int, for example. Also, please can you post the table definition?

Comment: `This is urgent because I have to submit this on 02/10/18 (American format)`  Lesson 1: *The first 90 percent of the code accounts for the first 90 percent of the development time. The remaining 10 percent of the code accounts for the other 90 percent of the development time.* Cargill, Bell Labs.  Plan accordingly

Comment: Check the actual types of each item in the debugger when the exception is thrown. At least one of these isn’t a string, bool, double, int, or DateTime.

Comment: Also, it would be really helpful if you were to post the full exception text since that usually tells you the two types involved in the cast exception.

Comment: split the creation of your Book in individual lines, so you can find which one is causing the problem and compare to your DB's content.
Also, checking for DBNull never hurts (as john said)

Comment: Yes stop freaking out, use the debugger and/or put everything into explicit variables before you call add, this way you will know what is causing the problem

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Sorry I was just panicking. Won't happen again. Thank You for the answer though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have this sitation, you have to split up that single line over more then one Code line. Use Temporary variables to store the rest of each array access + cast operation. That way you will get a meaningfull line/operation that is the problem. Something like this:

```
string title = i["title"];
string author = i["author"];
//lines omited

Book temp = new Book (title, author /*remaining temporary variables*/);
allBooks.Add(temp);
```

Do not worry about any performance or memory impacts from this. The normal and JiT compiler are pretty good at figuring out that it could cut out those variables in release builds. Sometimes they are so good even in Debug builds, it can be difficulty to force an Exception.